# Params being sent as [object Object] in GET request, not accepted by Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to execute a GET request to return a single "project", but when I send the params to Rails, they're being rejected because it's showing as [object Object], not the params that Rails is expecting.

This has worked for me before, so I'm a little lost.  I should be able to type in a number, which represents a project ID, and it should return that project.  Here is the index.html code where I'm entering the ID:

```
<form id="getProject" class="form-group">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="project[id]" placeholder="get one project id">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="get-project">get one project</button>
</form>
```

The event is triggered on submit:

```
$('#getProject').on('submit', onGetProject)
```

and onGetProject grabs the data and sends it to the API call:

```
const onGetProject = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const data = getFormFields(this)
  api.getProject(data)
    .then(ui.getProjectSuccess)
    .catch(ui.getProjectFailure)
}
```

API Call:

```
const getProject = (id) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  return $.ajax({
    url: config.apiOrigin + '/projects/' + id,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Token token=' + store.user.token
    }
  })
}
```

This is what shows in the terminal:

```
Started GET "/projects/[object%20Object]" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-27 
22:03:35 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"[object Object]"}
```

I wrote a script that should execute a GET request for a single ID, but that is returning everything, and not the "show" that I expect Rails to execute:

Script:

```
API="${API_ORIGIN:-http://localhost:4741}"
URL_PATH="/projects/${ID}"
curl "${API}${URL_PATH}" \
  --include \
  --request GET \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Token token=$TOKEN" \
  --data '{
    "project": {
      "id": "'"${INTEGER}"'"
    }
  }'
```

I'm using Ruby on Rails for my backend, and I am able to successfully execute a GET request which returns an index of all Projects and their nested tasks, as expected.  However, I am unable to get the single GET request to work, and am unsure what might be wrong with my code.

Please let me know if you need any additional code or information.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: `id` is an object, can you show what does `JSON.stringify(id)` print?

Comment: Sure!  It prints: `{"project":{"id":"2"}}`

Comment: you have: `'/projects/' + id`, if `id` is an object that is going to run [Object's toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function as it needs to be a string in order to concatenate it. Which is why you get `[object Object]`. You are probably needing to access your value like `id.project.id`, or call getProject like `getProject(data.project.id)` but would need to see how `getFormFields` is building the returned data

Comment: Ah that was it, Patrick!  I just needed to add `project.id` in my API call:

`const getProject = (id) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  return $.ajax({
    url: config.apiOrigin + '/projects/' + id.project.id
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Token token=' + store.user.token
    }
  })
}`

The GET was successful and now it's off to working on rendering it with Handlebars and figuring out how to display the nested "tasks" array that also came with the "project" object.

Thank you so much for your help, Patrick!!

Answer (score 0):

Since ID is an object, I needed to access the value more explicitly with `id.project.id`.

Once I substitued that in my API call, it successfully executed and the single Project I requested was returned.  Here is the working code:

```
    const getProject = (id) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      return $.ajax({
        url: config.apiOrigin + '/projects/' + id.project.id,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Token token=' + store.user.token
        }
      })
    }
```

Thank you, Patrick Evans!